# Trouble Pivoting Dataframe when Create a HeatMap Plot with Seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

I've been tried to create heatmap with seaborn. The dataframe I use is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv

The dataset has 5 columns namely: country,year,pop,continent,lifeExp and gdpPercap. I want to create a pivot table dataframe with year along x-axes, continent along y-axes and lifeExp filled within cells then plot it to heatmap.

The first thing I did is pivot the dataframe using codes

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv')
df2 = df1.pivot('year','continent','lifeExp')
```

but got an error.

So, I tried to change my codes to:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv')
print(df.head())
df2 = df.pivot_table(values= 'lifeExp', index=['year', 'continent'])
print(df2)
```

and the output of df2 is like this

> ```
>              lifeExp
> ```
>
> year continent
>   1952 Africa     39.135500
>       Americas   53.279840
>       Asia       46.314394
>       Europe     64.408500
>       Oceania    69.255000
>   1957 Africa     41.266346
>       Americas   55.960280
>       Asia       49.318544
>       Europe     66.703067
>       Oceania    70.295000
>       .....

and when I tried to plot it to seaborn

```
sns.heatmap(df2)
```

the lifeExp won't fill the heatmap.

How to fix?

Comment: hi can I ask you a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Hi ebuzz168,

It looks to me like you have set both 'year' and 'continent' as index and nothing as column. Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) the function call should look like this:

```
table = df.pivot_table(values='lifeExp', index='year', columns='continent', aggfunc=np.mean)
sns.heatmap(table)
```